# DLL load failed while importing winpty: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have installed JupyterLab on my system running Windows 8.1. I haven't used anaconda, but i have directly installed jupyterlab on a python installation using the following command: `pip install jupyterlab`.
**Python Version: 3.9.5**

When i start jupyterlab, it doesn't start and shows the following screen on my command line.

```
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:08.899 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2021-05-18 03:46:09.000 ServerApp] The 'min_open_files_limit' trait of a ServerApp instance expected an int, not the NoneType None.
[W 2021-05-18 03:46:10.225 ServerApp] Terminals not available (error was DLL load failed while importing winpty: The specified procedure could not be found.)
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:10.241 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from d:\ds projects\ds\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:10.241 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is D:\DS Projects\ds\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:10.281 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:21.104 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:21.487 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: D:\DS Projects
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:21.487 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.7.0 is running at:
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:21.487 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=28bc52a925d0808625cbd4254f6f92a0067faa2ae1bcb62d
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:21.487 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=28bc52a925d0808625cbd4254f6f92a0067faa2ae1bcb62d
[I 2021-05-18 03:46:21.487 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

It seems like jupyterlab starts and then shuts off due to some reason, that i wasn't able to figure out. furthermore, I also got a pop-up saying **Python has stopped working**.

The command line shows that some DLL file is missing. Furthermore, it also says that terminals are not available.

Comment: if you add more info on what is happening I might be able to help, that console doesnt show any errors. Does it happen after a while of using or immediately?

Comment: Are you using PowerShell?

Comment: @krassowski No, I am using command line.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR, in your environment, try:

```
pip install pywin32==228
```

or pywin32==225, or 227, or 300.

I had a similar problem recently and can reliably reproduce it with jupyter. For me this was due to a problem with pywin32 version 301. Yours may be similar (even though 301 came out after your issue was posted).

See my response here for more details and another possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67912292/4705724