# import win32api in python 3.7 resulting in dll import error

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, jupyter-notebook, dllimport

I am having the error while running jupyter notebook. Error replication:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.9
python
import win32api
```

The error was: `ImportError: DLL load failed`
After doing a some stackoverflow, I got to know that there are 2 dll files missing namely: `pythoncom37.dll` and `pywintypes37.dll`

I also got to know that I can run this post command: `pywin32_postinstall.py` in the Scripts folder. I ran this script. Restarted my pc. I manually download these two dll and copied it to my system32. After manually downloading, I started to have a different type of error: `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

I used anaconda and ran my jupyter notebook which was my main aim but can you please make me aware as what is going wrong?

Comment: Usually this is 32/64 bit mismatch in the dependent DLLs.

Comment: I have 64 bit python. So what else should I check?

Comment: That all the dependencies are also 64 bit. i.e. the DLLs that you downloaded.

Comment: I downloaded the 64 bit but not sure about others. But I solved it by just removing python and making a fresh install of python 3.9.5. Even though I still don't know what was the issue

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this recently, but with a different version of the DLLs. What solved it for me was using a different version of pywin32.
My solution (conda env, python 3.8.5):

```
pip install pywin32==300
```

or try 225, 227, 228. The latest pywin32 (301 as of this post) seems to be having dll search issues (I wouldn't be surprised if whatever version you were using is also having dll search issues). 301 was released after your issue started, but you may have a similar problem nonetheless.

There is currently an issue on pywin32 DLL loading failing: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1709

Factors involved (in my experience) include your PATH variable (if you're using conda). I haven't tested it myself, but I'd be curious to see if this issue occurs without conda. This issue stops happening for me if the first dlls found are those for 301. In my case, that means putting them in my C:\Windows\System32 folder (yeah I'm on Windows; joy).

So a possible solution #2 would be to run the pywin32 post install script which should be located under your venv/Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py

To try that solution, open an ADMIN command prompt (very important that it's admin), navigate to your venv, and run:

```
ppython.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py --install
```

You shouldn't HAVE to do this, but if you just need a one-off solution and it works, great!

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --upgrade pywin32 ==225` worked for me. Tried version 300 and was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: I spend a few hours on this "fun". In the end it turned out that Python 3.8 ran just fine (executed correctly the "import win32com.client" line) -- and the **problem was Spyder**. I uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version and it all started to work. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

In may case helped starting exe-application "As administrator"